# Allow swipeing only to upwards unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code below works for detecting swipes and adding force to my game object. However, my aim is to let the user swipe only upwards(Can be up left, up right but never to down). I mean only if user swipes up, AddForce method will be called. When user swipes down nothing will happen. Is it possible to do that, if yes how?

```
    public class SwipeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 startPos, endPos, direction;
    float touchTimeStart, touchTimeFinish, timeInterval;
    [Range(0.05f, 1f)]
    public float throwForse = 0.5f;


    void Update()
    {
        
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            touchTimeStart = Time.time;
            startPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            
        }
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            
            touchTimeFinish = Time.time;
            timeInterval = touchTimeFinish - touchTimeStart;
            endPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            direction = startPos - endPos;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(-direction / timeInterval * throwForse);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Palo please don't answer in comments. Just just add an answer for the question, your answer it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just clamp the direction to be nonnegative? For instance, before the last line add something like:

This would be for upward and right:

```
direction = Vector2.Max(direction, Vector2.Zero);
```

and this would be for all upward:

```
direction = new Vector2(direction.x, Math.Max(direction.y, 0));
```

and I suggest you use

```
direction = endPos - startPos;
```

instead of the other way as in your original code, as this way it represents that movement vector correctly. Then remove the negative sign in `AddForce` in front of the `direction` as well. Thus:

```
void Update()
{        
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        touchTimeStart = Time.time;
        startPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        
    }
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {            
        touchTimeFinish = Time.time;
        timeInterval = touchTimeFinish - touchTimeStart;
        endPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        Vector2 direction = endPos - startPos;
        direction = new Vector2(direction.x, Math.Max(direction.y, 0)); 
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(direction / timeInterval * throwForse);            
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, firsly Vector2.Zero should be Vector2.zero because I get error when I write uppercase. Secondly, your code ristricted the swipeing directions but not in the way I wanted. With your code I am able to swipe up and right like a L shape area. I cant swipe to the up left or the left side of my screen.

Comment: So I guess this allows us only to swipe up and right (Which are positive directions) But I want to be able to swipe left as well

Comment: Oh yes, that's seems to be difference between UnityEngine.CoreModule.Vector2 vs. System.Numerics.Vector2. The first has "zero", the other one has "Zero". First to understand you, so you want to allow any direction upwards, but not downwards? And do you want to completely filter out (i.e. ignore) all downward guestures as if they did not occur, or do you want to keep the horizontal part of them (left and right) but at the same Y-coordinate?

Comment: I want to ignore downward gestures.

Comment: @asdasdasd I have updated the answer for ignoring downward. I do not have a C# compiler, but I am sure you manage, if there is something more to touch in the code. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you it works. There is just one error. For the others may benefit from this answer, Math.Max should be Mathf.Max You can edit your answer if you like.

Comment: Happy, if it made you move ahead. I believe Math.Max should be available in Unity too. It's been with C# since very long. Someplace they even say it works faster than Mathf.Max.